# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo and extends ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm new to android and started to follow [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

My code consist of following files:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lukas.tracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <!-- Location found activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".LocationFound"
        android:label="@string/activity_new_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LocationFound

```
package com.example.lukas.tracker;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LocationFound  extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_found);

        // get action bar   
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.lukas.tracker;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                // search action
                return true;
            case R.id.action_location_found:
                // location found
                LocationFound();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                // refresh
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                // help action
                return true;
            case R.id.action_check_updates:
                // check for updates action
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    private void LocationFound() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationFound.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

activity_location_found.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location is found. Drop a Message here"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have two questions.

1. If I run this code, app crashies after i click on gps icon (location found)

[image]

and throws errors:

```
01-11 20:17:09.361    1893-1893/com.example.lukas.tracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lukas.tracker, PID: 1893
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lukas.tracker/com.example.lukas.tracker.LocationFound}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.lukas.tracker.LocationFound.onCreate(LocationFound.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I think problem is at line

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

actionBar is null, but I don't know what to change to get actual reference to actionBar.

2. In tutorial is used

   public class MainActivity extends Activity{

but if I followed tutorial, there was no action bar shown, I have to change it to

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

if I'm correct it's from support package and it's used for apps for lower level api

but when I started project I chose min 14 / target 21

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lukas.tracker"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

so why is not working just with `extends Activity`?

thanks for help

edit:

[image]

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
        android:title="@string/action_location_found"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Refresh -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Help -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
        android:title="@string/action_help"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <!-- Check updates -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity (activity from the support package), that means your application uses AppCompat theme.

Since your `minSdk` is 14, you shouldn't be using the support package at all.

1. Make both your activities to extend `Activity`.
2. Then in your `styles.xml` have your `AppTheme` refer a newer theme, e.g.:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   </style>
   ```

Comment: thx, that style works, now it runs and also when I choose item in menu, it opens new window,but icons disappeared from top bar, see edit in my main post for printscreen. Can you tell me  where is problem now?

Comment: @sala84 since now you're not using the support package, you shouldn't be using the custom namespace `app`. So just change to `android:showAsAction` and you should be fine.

Comment: I changed app->android , but now I get error on line:<item android:...... it says menu items should specify a title

Comment: @sala84 post your new menu_main.xml

Comment: @sala84 remove this line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` from the menu tag.

Comment: now error on line android:showAsAction... -> should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library...

Comment: @sala84 I believe that's a warning, not an error so you're actually fine. However, to avoid that warning, remove the support package dependency from build.gradle.